# MVC Login. User.Identity always empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-7

I am trying to save information about the login in the HttpContext.Current.User.Identity in a asp.net-mvc5 proyect. But allways is empty.

Firt of all, a have a View with controller.
When you click on login button, call to the controller:

```
public ActionResult Button1_Click(string user, string pass)
{
    bool result = _model.ValidateLogin(user, pass, 3, false);

    DirectResult r = new DirectResult();

    // Do some Authentication...
    if (!result)
    {
        r.Success = false;
        r.ErrorMessage = "Invalid username or password.";
    }

    return r;
}
```

The method ValidateLogin, first check the user is on database, and with the id create a cookie:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.Initialize();
System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, userId.ToString(), now, now.Add(System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.Timeout), checkRemember, string.Empty, System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
string hash = System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
System.Web.HttpCookie cookie = new System.Web.HttpCookie(System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hash);
if (ticket.IsPersistent)
 cookie.Expires = now.AddYears(1);
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

But when i try to check the User.Identify always is empty and "IsAuthenticated" is false:

```
protected override System.Security.Principal.IIdentity GetClientIdentity()
{
    IIdentity identity = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
    if (identity.IsAuthenticated)
        return identity;
    else
        throw new AuthorizationDeniedException("Not logged in",false);

}
```

Why? Any idea?

**Edit for add web.config:**

In the web config, i have:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Login/Index" protection="All" timeout="120" name=".ASPXAUTH" path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" defaultUrl="default.html" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" enableCrossAppRedirects="false"/>
 </authentication>
 <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
 </authorization>
 <location path="Login">
      <system.web>
           <authorization>
                <allow users="*"/>
           </authorization>
      </system.web>
 </location>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you have missed to override  FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate method in global.asax
Checkout this sample for the solution
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578374/AplusBeginner-splusTutorialplusonplusCustomplusF

Comment: Just to point out `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest` is also listed if working with versions >=4